# Have different rails app with same backend and database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, web-applications

I am suppose to develop multiple web-apps that will share the same backend and database. 
I thought of doing this by developing a single Rails JSON API with a Postgresql db. I would then have my different "client" rails applications that will request the same JSON API either in AJAX (using JQUERY) or through their own set of rails controllers.

What do you think about this solution ? Am I going in the right direction ? Is there something better to do ?

==> I was also thinking maybe it is possible to have a single rails app that renders different html depending on the origin of the request ? what do you think ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to render different layouts and and views depending on the request type & origin. You should go with this idea of single rails application.

Comment: thanks @MuhammadYawarAli for your response. Could you explain how you do that (so far I have only seen the possibility to render different formats depending what the type of request). Also what do you think is wrong with the JSON API approach ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with json API approach and i used layout changing method to render different views my scenairio was to display different views when open on desktop browser and different for mobile browsers so i wrote a route method in the application controller to set the route based on request headers. It worked fine and app is live now.

Comment: Couldn't you have used responsive css for that?

Answer (score 0):

JSON approach will be slower than having your application serve differently based on the request. You would need to build and parse json objects, handle 2 way communication of that object, it's clearly more work per request.

You can find out all kind of information from the request object in your controllers, such as `request.referer` for the source of the incoming request. Using this information you should be able to make a decision on how to serve your data to the user.

Comment: The truth is I have already started with the JSON API approach, I might go back from scratch. I also noticed that my app was very slow with the API approach because the basic pattern is that it needs first to go through the client rails app' controller which is then responsible for calling the API which then renders the JSON response. If I stick to this, I was thinking of making every request using AJAX to directly call the API asynchronously, but then I dont really see the opportunity of using Rails for the client app anymore. Wouldnt AngularJS or ReactJS be a nicer choice then?